# Error con array (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, split

Tengo un array que tiene variados elementos, todo esto contenido en una base de datos, pero al querer eliminarlo con un metodo (con split) no me deja y me tira el error del titulo, como lo soluciono?, y a todo esto, como puedo ver como va cambiando el array a medida que funcion la aplicación?, adjunto codigo

View events:

```
public class ViewEventsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {
//al mantener la wea apretada
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_events);

    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ltvListaEventos);
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
    int dia,mes,anio;
    dia=mes=anio=0;

    dia=bundle.getInt("dia");
    mes=bundle.getInt("mes");
    anio=bundle.getInt("anio");
    String cadena= dia+" - "+ mes + " - "+ anio;

    BDSQLite bd= new BDSQLite(getApplicationContext(), "eventos", null,1);
    db= bd.getReadableDatabase();

    String sql="select * from eventos where fechadesde='"+cadena+"'";
    Cursor c;



    String nombreEvento,fechadesde,horadesde,fechahasta,horahasta,descripcion,ubicacion;
    try {
        c=db.rawQuery(sql,null);
        arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        if(c==null||c.getCount()==0) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No hay eventos disponibles", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }




        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                nombreEvento=c.getString(1);
                ubicacion=c.getString(2);
                fechadesde=c.getString(3);
                horadesde=c.getString(4);
                fechahasta=c.getString(5);
                horahasta=c.getString(6);
                descripcion=c.getString(7);
                arrayAdapter.add(nombreEvento+", "+ubicacion+", "+fechadesde+", "+horadesde+", "+fechahasta+", "+horahasta+", "+descripcion);
            } while(c.moveToNext());
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

    }catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Error: "+ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.finish();

    }


}



private  void  eliminar(String dato){
    String []datos= dato.split(", ");

    String sql="delete from eventos where nombreEvento='"+datos[0]+"' and" +
            " ubicacion='"+datos[1]+"' and fechadesde='"+datos[2]+"' and " +
            "horadesde='"+datos[3]+"' and fechahasta='"+datos[4]+"' and horahasta='"+datos[5]+"' and descripcion='"+datos[6] + " '; ";
    try {

        arrayAdapter.remove(dato);         //eliminar del menú
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        db.execSQL(sql);


        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Evento eliminado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Error:"+ ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    CharSequence []items= new CharSequence[2];
    items[0]="Eliminar Evento";
    items[1]="Cancelar";
    builder.setTitle("Eliminar evento")
            .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                    if(i==0){
                        //eliminar evento
                        eliminar(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                    }
                }
            });

    AlertDialog dialog= builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    return false;
}
```

Add events:

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText nombreEvento, ubicacion, fechadesde, horadesde, fechahasta, horahasta;
    private EditText descripcion;

    private Button guardar, cancelar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        nombreEvento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNombreEvento);
        ubicacion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUbicacion);
        fechadesde = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFechaDesde);
        fechahasta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFechaHasta);
        horadesde = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtHorainicio);
        horahasta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtHoraHasta);
        descripcion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDescripcion);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        int dia = 0, mes = 0, anio = 0;

        dia=bundle.getInt("dia");
        mes=bundle.getInt("mes");
        anio=bundle.getInt("anio");


        fechadesde.setText(dia + " - " + mes + " - " + anio);
        fechahasta.setText(dia + " - " + mes + " - " + anio);

        guardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnguardar);
        cancelar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncancelar);
        guardar.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancelar.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == guardar.getId()) {
            //guardar datos cajas de texto
            BDSQLite bd = new BDSQLite(getApplication(), "eventos", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = bd.getWritableDatabase();



            String sql = "insert into eventos" +
                    "(nombreEvento, ubicacion, fechadesde, horadesde, fechahasta, horahasta," +
                    "descripcion) values('" +
                    nombreEvento.getText()+
                    "','"+ ubicacion.getText()+
                    "','" +fechadesde.getText()+
                    "','" +horadesde.getText()+
                    "','"+fechahasta.getText()+
                    "','"+horahasta.getText()+
                    "','"+descripcion.getText();
            try {
                db.execSQL(sql);
                nombreEvento.setText("");
                ubicacion.setText("");
                fechadesde.setText("");
                fechahasta.setText("");
                horadesde.setText("");
                horahasta.setText("");
                descripcion.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Evento guardado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Error"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        } else {
            this.finish();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

BDSQLite:

```
public class BDSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private String sql = "create table eventos(" +
            "idEvento int identity,"+
            "nombreEvento varchar(40)," +
            "ubicacion varchar(60)," +
            "fechadesde date,"+
            "horadesde time,"+
            "fechahasta date,"+
            "horahasta time," +
            "descripcion varchar(60))";

    public BDSQLite(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(sql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

> ERROR:
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5 caused by:
>   edito Cabe destacar que el error se genera en eliminar(String dato)
>   que se encuentra en View events al final. De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Parece obvio que el array datos no tiene siempre al menos 7 elementos y, por tanto, no se puede crear la consulta. Añade una comprobación y usa el log para mostrar los valores, así podrás ver lo que vale el array o el texto desde el que lo generas

Comment: Como dice Pablo, parece que al hacer el split no se genera un array de 7 posiciones como quieres tu al hacer datos[6]. Mira que string le pasas a elimminar cuando te da el error.

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info) Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**En este caso debes asegurar que el valor de la cadena `dato`, siempre contenga 7 valores separados por ","**, por ejemplo:

```
String dato = "valor1, valor2, valor3, valor4, valor5, valor6, valor7";
```

esto para que al realizar:

```
  String []datos = dato.split(", ");
```

y obtengas los 7 elementos del array que necesitas para construir tu query:

```
  String sql = "delete from eventos where nombreEvento='"+datos[0]+"' and" +
            " ubicacion='"+datos[1]+"' and fechadesde='"+datos[2]+"' and " +
            "horadesde='"+datos[3]+"' and fechahasta='"+datos[4]+"' and horahasta='"+datos[5]+"' and descripcion='"+datos[6] + " '; ";
```

de otra forma si no contiene los 7 valores obtendras el error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dice @PabloLozano, el error ocurre en que el array que se generá tras llamar a la función split, tiene un tamaño menor de 7. Este array se crea a partir de un String, que se genera en la siguiente línea de código dentro del método onItemLongClick:

```js
adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()
```

Con el código que nos has dado, no podemos saber que objetos estas recuperando en ese bucle, pero desde luego el método toString no está devolviendo lo que esperas. Tendrías que asegurar de qué clase es el objeto devuelto con:

```js
adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)
```

Una vez que tengas claro que clase de objeto es, podrás ver su método toString(), y ahí encontrarás la raíz de este problema.

Nos faltaría esa parte de código para poder dar una solución completa a este problema, pero lo que si puedo hacer es orientarte hacía donde debes mirar, e incitarte a que lo arregles por ti mismo. Si aún así prefieres copiar el código de la clase, podrémos encontrar aquello qué está causando el problema.

Comment: Ya encontré el error gracias, el input lo hace el usuario, por lo que al tener un campo vacío (edit tex) tira el error, muchas gracias, lo que si, intente crear un if para que si algún campo estuviese vacío no guardara evento (este evento guardado tiene menos de 7 elementos por lo que intentar eliminarlo genera error)

Comment: Me alegro que hayas encontrado el error que tenias! Un saludo.